# Remove linearly dependent vectors from a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

This may be a redundant question because I'm still studying this field.
I'm attempting to write an algorithm that removes linearly dependent vectors from a matrix in a simple way.

First approach was to rewrite the definition
$c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n = 0$ as

$
\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} c_1 & \cdots & c_n \end{pmatrix} = 0
$

and solve for the constants, not sure if this is an optimal or even correct approach but I can't seem to reach some identification of a linearly dependent vector.

how can one approach this correctly?

Comment: I think you want an algorithm, not a function.

Comment: @Riquelme Correct. I meant a programming function and not a mathematical function, I'm used to computer science references.

Comment: The method you meant is valid see: https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/lindep/lindep.html. Another approach if dividing each row by each other row and each column by each column yield save value respectively. The later is easier to program.

Comment: The QR decomposition mentioned in an answer below is probably the most computationally-efficient method, but you can also do this with good old Gaussian elimination or the Gram-Schmidt process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) programmatically (e.g., using [numpy.linalg.qr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.qr.html)), then every $v_i$ corresponding zero diagonal component of $R$ are what you're supposed to remove!

That is, once you get the upper triangular matrix, $R$, every $v_i$ for which $R_{ii}=0$ is the vector linearly dependent on $v_1, \ldots, v_{i-1}$.